# Are there any bungee jumping sites in Myanmar?

Tags: activities, myanmar, extreme-sports

What it says in the tin: are there any bungee jumping sites - preferably in the Irrawady or Central Myanmar region - that are open throughout out the year as opposed to open as special events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος, I doubt that Irrawaddy or Central region have bungee-jumping capabilities, but not based on an undated article that mentions "it may just be a matter of time".

In my case I doubt *anywhere* in Myanmar yet offers bungee jumping on a regular basis.

From the same site as that article ([Myanmar Burma.com](http://www.myanmarburma.com/blog/647/6-great-places-for-bungeejumping)) the question is posed:

> Who is going to be the first to take a leap in Myanmar?

In this case the article is dated, 26 Mar 2013.

On the Myanmar forum [mingalapar](http://mingalapar.com/forum/index.php/topic/332-bungee-jumping-in-myanmar/) Maibpenrai, showing as from Bangkok/Yangon, posted shortly after the above (15 June 2013 - 07:57):

> It seems to be than Bungee Jumping in Myanmar is not available yet

Thereafter it is a matter of assumptions and deductions. The Burmese do not have a cultural heritage such as Vanuatu has for [land diving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBDkVXqlVMw) and the introduction of bungee jumping there can be expected to relate specifically to the expansion of tourism. (In [2015](http://www.myanmartourism.org/images/tourism-statistics/2015.pdf) tourist visits numbered only 1.3M.) For that advertising can be expected nowadays and this OP's failure to find what he was looking for can be taken to indicate that such does not exist (yet). The signs are however that it will do before very long, so should be worth monitoring the situation.

Answer (score 3):

> ## Myamar Offers Fine Bungee-Jumping Sites
>
> #### You can bungee-jump from almost anywhere—towers, jagged cliffs and even helicopters. So it may just be a matter of time before extreme sports enthusiasts can take the plunge in Myanmar.
>
> [image: Myamar offers Fine Bungee-Jumping sites]
>
> <sup>image source from: [jumpintheair.com](//jumpintheair.com)</sup>
>
> Although this country’s tourism industry is still [in its infancy](//myanmarburma.com/blog/228/myanmar-a-newborn-baby-on-its-feet-and-learning-to-walk), it’s already grabbing the attention of [thrill-seekers](//myanmarburma.com/article/783/adventure-travel-in-myanmar-burma) looking for a remote spot to explore, the same kind of folks who love bungee-jumping. The [potential spots](//myanmarburma.com/tags/mountain) for this activity are endless.
>
> [Travelers](//myanmarburma.com/blog/207/guess-whos-coming-to-myanmar-besides-you) may one day be able to dive off the 102-meter-high [Gokteik Viaduct](//myanmarburma.com/blog/307/10-mustvisit-destinations-youve-never-heard-of), the tallest bridge in Myanmar (Burma), or the steep jungle walls of Bahmo Gorge. In downtown [Yangon](//myanmarburma.com/regions/20/yangon-region), there’s the [Maha Bandula](//myanmarburma.com/attraction/37/maha-bandula-garden) Bridge and the 22-story [Traders Hotel](//myanmarburma.com/blog/90/traders-hotel-lobby-cheesecake-to-go-oops).
>
> Of course, these are just ideas. You’ll just have to wait and see where bungee-jumping will be first offered in Myanmar.

[(source)](//myanmarburma.com/attraction/565/myamar-offers-fine-bungeejumping-sites) [spelling errors: "Mya**n**mar"]

But, I doubt that Irrawdy or Central region have bungee-jumping capabilities at all.

Comment: You can't bungee-jump off a tower or a jagged cliff!

Comment: @TonyK Yeah, isn't there any regular cliff?